# Binding from SelectedItem Object in ListBox to ComboBox

Tags: mvvm, binding, combobox, entity, master-detail

Here is part of my UI:
http://imgur.com/MtXSCnL

In the Department List, I have a list of Department objects (I am using the MVVM pattern). I access these objects through an Observable collection in the *DepartmentViewModel*.

I am using the Entity Framework to link with my database and I am trying to do the following:

I am binding the *SelectedItem* in the Department list to display information in the *Department* Groupbox. The problem occurs when I try to bind the department's Foreign Key (Office in this case) to the Combobox. I have an *Office* property of type *Office* in my Department viewmodel however I would like to display the OfficeName property of the Office object in the combobox and be able to modify  and save changes to Department (the logic for this is already done).

How do I bind a property of type *Office* to display the *OfficeName* in the combobox?

**DepartmentViewModel:**

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Office
    /// </summary>
    private const string OfficePropertyName = "Office";
    public Office Office
    {
        get { return _newDepartment.Office; }
        set
        {
            _newDepartment.Office = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(OfficePropertyName);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Office> _OfficeList;

    private const string OfficeListPropertyName = "OfficeList";
    public ObservableCollection<Office> OfficeList
    {
        get
        {
            return _OfficeList;
        }
        set
        {
            _OfficeList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(OfficeListPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

**DepartmentView**

```
            <ListBox Grid.Row="0"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding DepartmentList}" 
                 DisplayMemberPath="DepartmentName"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDepartment}"/>


            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBox Margin="10,10" Text="{Binding SelectedDepartment.DepartmentName}" />
                <TextBox Margin="10,10" Text="{Binding SelectedDepartment.Supervisor}" />

                <!-- List of all Office...here is where I want to show the selected office from the selected item in department list -->
                <ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10"
              ItemsSource="{Binding OfficeList}"
              DisplayMemberPath="OfficeName"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Office}" />

            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Isn't there an OfficeName property in Office class?

Comment: Yes the problem I'm having is linking the SelectedItem from the department list to display the appropriate OfficeName in the Office combobox.
Ex: When user clicks an entry in the Department list, the form gets filled out showing the information. The user can change the information and save it which modifies the database row.

Comment: You bind ComboBox's SelectedItem to Office and ItemsSource to OfficeList, you cannot see the OfficeName on ComboBox since Office is not initialized to a value or its value does not reference equal to one in the OfficeList

Comment: What part of your code doesn't actually work? It looks like what you have done is correct. What is the actual issue? What is shown in the combo box at the moment?

Comment: The issue I am having is with the comboBox. Yes, data is displayed correctly however I want the value in the Combobox to display the correct value depending on the selected value in the listbox.
Ex: I select a Department in the listbox (a department belongs to an Office in the database 1 office has departments) and I want the office to appear selected in the combobox. If the user changes the combobox value and clicks Save, the Department now belongs to another office.